# How to add projection to moloquent select

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

i know, i can do this in mongoDb to get all mongoIds:

```
db.getCollection('foo').find({},{_id:1})
```

This returns a set of all entries with just one element, the _id.

I need to this in PHP. I'm using Laravel 5.3 and Moloquent and could'nt find a way to add a projection to my select.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Moloquent aimed at bridging Eloquent & Mongo, the usage of Moloquent should almost be the same as Eloquent. I believe a simple Eloquent select would do the trick.

Try this. I haven't try it yet. It should work as expected:

```
$results = SomeModel::get(['_id']);
```

Comment: I checked this and it seems to do what i need, but it just leads into an error: Failed to read 4 bytes from socket within 300000 milliseconds. Did'nt sort that out yet :-(

Comment: What's the size of your records? It looks like timeout due to excessive reads. It may due to the fact that `::get` is getting all the records at once.

Comment: Its just about 117000 records, don't think that's massive. Thats why i only want to get the ids, to split them up and handle them in chunks.

Comment: If you want to chunk them up, then maybe you will like to do `::take(100)->get(..)` to get the 100 records, and use `->skip(x)` to do the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Projection is very important to optimize the queries and not to obtain a complete object. Use `get` method with a list of parameters to do the projection. You can be guided by this example:

```
$clients = Clients::where("number", "=", "9510149")->get(['complete_name', 'age']);    
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    echo $client->complete_name;
    echo $client->age;
    echo $client->id;
}
```

By default always the `id` parameter is included in the projection, if you try to access an attribute that was not projected it will give a null value.